# Random mc in Animate CC using javascript HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, adobe

In a Animate CC Canvas project, I have several mc's in the library with these linkage names: `card1`, `card2`, `card3`... and want to put a random mc on stage using Javascript/HTML5 code.

```
var container, c, card; // basic stuff

function init() {
  c = createjs;
  container = new c.Container();
  stage.addChild(container);

  var m = 1; // a random number
  card = new lib.this["card" + m](); // GIVES ERROR. This is AS3 style.
  //card = new lib.card1();  // WORKS FINE!
  container.addChild(card);
  card.x = 800;
  card.y = 250;
}
```

I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'card1' of undefined.

Any ideas, please? :)

Comment: Does your `lib` have a `this` property? If so what is it? And what is `container`? What is `addChild`? Maybe you are referring to  `appendChild`? You really did not provide enough code.

Comment: Sorry if I took too much for granted. I have updated the code.
I'm an used to AS3. :)

Comment: What is the name of your clip in your lib? Are you trying to do this: `new lib["card+m"]()`? @theAlexandrian is right, unless there is a `this` object in your lib (which I am guessing there is not, unless you injected it somehow). AS3 and JS have the same bracket-access code, so it just depends on what the format is. What would it look like if you hard-coded it? `new lib.card1` or something?

Comment: Thank you @Lanny!
I think that was the only combination I didn't try: No dot between lib and [.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> card = new lib.this["card" + m](); // GIVES ERROR. This is AS3 style.  
> // card = new lib.card1();  // WORKS FINE!
> ```

From this I have two points to clear:

- This is because we do not use `this` keyword as a property of some object. We use it in the object's methods as a reference to it.

  ```
  var foo = { x: 1, y: 2 };
  console.log(foo.this);      // → undefined
  console.log(foo.this["x"]); // → Type Error

  var bar = { x: 1, y: 2, showX: function () { return this["x"] } }
  console.log(bar.showX());   // → 1
  ```

  But you can have a property named `this`:

  ```
  var foo { this: 1, that: 2 }
  console.log(foo.this);      // → 1
  ```
- You can access an object's properties using the `.` notation or the `[]` notation, *(no need for `this`)* like so:

  ```
  var foo = { x: 1, y: 2 };
  console.log(foo.x);         // → 1
  console.log(foo["y"]);      // → 2
  ```

So what you need to do is:

```
card = new lib["card" + m]();
```

---

The following is an example using divs. I tried to follow your code to keep it similar. The `lib` object has 4 constructors `card1` to `card4` as properties, each generating cards with a specific color.

```js
const createjs = {
    Container: function () {
      this.elt = document.createElement("div");
      this.elt.classList.add("container");
    }
  },
  
  Card = function () {
    this.elt = document.createElement("span");
    this.elt.classList.add("card");
  },
  
  lib = {
    card1: function () {
      this.elt = new Card().elt;
      this.elt.style.background = "lightblue";
    },
    card2: function () {
      this.elt = new Card().elt;
      this.elt.style.background = "gold";
    },
    card3: function () {
      this.elt = new Card().elt;
      this.elt.style.background = "lightgreen";
    },
    card4: function () {
      this.elt = new Card().elt;
      this.elt.style.background = "#f76";
    }
  };


function init() {
  let container = new createjs.Container().elt;
  stage.appendChild(container);

  for (let m = 1; m < 5; m++) {
    let card = new lib["card" + m]().elt;
  
    card.style.width = 80 + "px";
    card.style.height = 100 + "px";
    container.appendChild(card);
  }
}  

init();
```

```css
#stage {
  background: #e85;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.container {
  margin: 60px;
  background: #fff3;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you all! Thank you @theAlexandrian. 
That simple dot! XD